# Need to get primary Ember outlet in the Rails outlet correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js

I'm moving a part of an app to Ember as the first part of hopefully migrating the full app. It is a Rails app and I am at proof-of-concept stage. In my Rails view (index2.html.erb) I have the following:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  <div>
    here is outlet:
    {{outlet}}
  </div>
</script>
within index2
```

However, this renders the Ember output at the bottom of the html page like this:

[image]

How would I fix this? Even if I put my Ember outlet in my Rails layout, it render the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When declaring your ember app, include a reference to a div, as such:

```
App = Ember.Application.create({
  rootElement: '#app'
});
```

And then create a div with that id in the location where you want your app to appear:

```
<div id="app"></div>
```

And now your app will be inserted within that div.